# How to change the body of one part using Email::MIME? Or: Who does body_set work?

Tags: perl, email, mime, perl-module, mime-mail

I am trying to change the body text of a part inside a multi-part MIME-Email using `Email::MIMEs` (1.926) `walk_parts` and `body_set`.

The change is there but when sending the mail the old/non-changed mail text is being sent.
The question is: What do I have to do to 'activate' my changes?

See:

```
use Email::MIME;

my $raw_message_text = q!Date: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 08:02:39 +0100
From: Me <me@example.com>
To: You <you@example.com>
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="------------010309070301040606000908"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------010309070301040606000908
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

this is a test

--------------010309070301040606000908
Content-Type: text/plain;
 name="file-to-attach.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="file-to-attach.txt"

dGV4dCBpbnNpZGUgYXR0YWNobWVudAoK
--------------010309070301040606000908--
!;


my $parsed_email = Email::MIME->new($raw_message_text);

$parsed_email->walk_parts(sub {
    my ($part) = @_;
    return if $part->subparts; # multipart
    return unless ($part->content_type =~ /text\/plain.*charset=utf-8/i);
    $part->body_set("new body text");
});

print "As you see the change is there:\n";
$parsed_email->walk_parts(sub {
    my ($part) = @_;
    return if $part->subparts; # multipart
    my $body = $part->body;
    print "Body:$body\n";
});

print "But the email object itself doesn't notice that:\n\n";

print $parsed_email->as_string;
```

This will first show the changed body text, so you see it is there! But when the whole mail is shown the old body text is used. The same will happen if I just send the email using `Email::Sender`. So I wonder what the correct usage of `body_set` is...

Comment: it works for me with 1.910

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem as well.  Eventually I realized all that's missing from the original poster, is just the following:

```
my @new_parts = $parsed_email->parts;
$parsed_email->parts_set( \@new_parts );
```

add the above before the final as_string call, and you are good.

Comment: Indeed! It worked without `parts_set` in Debian's version 1.910-1 but it is required at least in 1.926-1 (Debian Jessie).

Answer (score 0):

The `walk_parts` doesn't seem to work properly i had to use the old classic method, i'm not sure if there is something broken with the new version but with this method it works, you'll just need to replace your code somehow:

This solution isn't efficient at all and i know its heavy on the memory but i'm lazy, i think i should look for another library with this model.

```
my @parts = $parsed->subparts;
my @new_parts;
if (@parts) {
  foreach (@parts)
  {
    my $part = $_;
    print $part->content_type."\r\n";    
    if ($part->content_type =~ /text\/plain.*charset=utf-8/i) {
     $part->body_set("new body text");
     push @new_parts, $part;
    } else {
     push @new_parts, $part;
    }
   }
} else {
 print 'single part';#to replace for single mime
}
$parsed->parts_set(\@new_parts);
```

Comment: Then do not be that lazy and update the answer soon :)